# Notification deleteIntent does not work

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I've read several questions concerning similair issues, but they do not provide me with the solution.

In my Android app I fire off a notification (in the Application class to be specific, which is actually started from a C2DM push event).

I then want to receive an Intent when the "clear all" button is pressed on the notifications:

```
notification.deleteIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(this, NotificationDeleteReceiver.class), 0);
```

In my NotificationDeleteReceiver.class I got the onReceive method:

```
public class NotificationDeleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

In my manifest file I got:

```
<receiver android:name="NotificationDeleteReceiver">
</receiver>
```

But still onReceive does not get called. What could I be doing wrong? Is there any smart way to debug and see if an Intent really is fired?

Do I need some kind of intent filter or should it be fine?

Any tips welcome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to use the intent with a BroadcastReceiver, you should use [`PendingIntent.getBroadcast`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29) instead of `PendingIntent.getService`. You might also need to setup an appropriate intent filter.

Comment: And how is supposed we can set an intent filter to the intent??