# Detect if notification has been deleted

Tags: android, android-notifications, accessibilityservice

I have the following problem. I want to detect when a notification has been removed from the notification bar.

I can scan notifications with an AccessbilityService and casting its ParcelableData to a notification

```
Notification notif = (Notification) event.getParcelableData();
```

One thought of mine was, utilizing if the PendingIntent of the notification has been clicked, but I can't find anything on how to detect that.

Any ideas? I am kind of desperate... trying it for hours now.

Comment: you could find your answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811876/notification-deleteintent-does-not-work

Comment: I am actually not looking for my own notifications to get detected. I am looking for other packages/apps' notifications to get deleted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very similar question has already been answered here on SO:

[Detect a new Android notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367196/detect-a-new-android-notification)

In short, it's possible to detect when a new notification appears, but that's about it. You can't detect when notifications have been dismissed.

Comment: hmpf. Maybe I should take an approach as gone through here: http://gmariotti.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/how-to-write-dashclock-extension_23.html?m=1

Comment: That's basically the first answer in my link. There's no doubt that the link provides the anser.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a setDeleteIntent on the Notification.Builder:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setDeleteIntent(android.app.PendingIntent)

It can be use to do what you want (I guess it's too late for you but it can help someone else)

Comment: This is not what the OP wanted, he wants to detect the removal of notifications from other apps. Not sure why this has the most upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know, this is impossible unless you have root, but starting from android 4.3 , which was released just yesterday, it is possible. here are some links:

[android developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/07/android-43-and-updated-developer-tools.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20blogspot/hsDu%20%28Android%20Developers%20Blog%29):

> Notification access — Your apps can now access and interact with the
>   stream of status bar notifications as they are posted. You can display
>   them in any way you want, including routing them to nearby Bluetooth
>   devices, and you can update and dismiss notifications as needed.

[android developer website](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#NotificationListener):

> Android 4.3 adds a new service class, NotificationListenerService,
>   that allows your app to receive information about new notifications as
>   they are posted by the system.
>
> If your app currently uses the accessibility service APIs to access
>   system notifications, you should update your app to use these APIs
>   instead.

[android developer website - API description](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html#43-beautiful-apps):

Access to notifications

> Notifications have long been a popular Android feature because they
>   let users see information and updates from across the system, all in
>   one place. Now in Android 4.3, apps can observe the stream of
>   notifications with the user's permission and display the notifications
>   in any way they want, including sending them to nearby devices
>   connected over Bluetooth.
>
> You can access notifications through new APIs that let you register a
>   notification listener service and with permission of the user, receive
>   notifications as they are displayed in the status bar. Notifications
>   are delivered to you in full, with all details on the originating app,
>   the post time, the content view and style, and priority. You can
>   evaluate fields of interest in the notifications, process or add
>   context from your app, and route them for display in any way you
>   choose.
>
> The new API gives you callbacks when a notification is added, updated,
>   and removed (either because the user dismissed it or the originating
>   app withdrew it). You'll be able to launch any intents attached to the
>   notification or its actions, as well as dismiss it from the system,
>   allowing your app to provide a complete user interface to
>   notifications.

and of course, the API documentation of this new listener, in [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#onNotificationRemoved%28android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification%29)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you extend the NotificationListener and do your own stuff in the callbacks:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html