# What is the best way to determine that a notification has been removed or dismissed by the user?

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I have to fire my notification 30 times in order to play the alarm sound 30 seconds continuously. But the process needs to get out of the loop if the user remove the notification from the notification pool? What is the best way to do this?

```
for(int i ; i < 30; i++) {
    notificationManager.notify(tag, NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505578/detect-if-notification-has-been-deleted. I think this might help you

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to just play a long sound on the notification; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809399/android-notification-sound

Comment: @RichardTingle IMO, if I set a short notification sound, it could mean that I don't want it to be too long, for any reason, so I wouldn't play something that the user didn't choose (either a longer sound or the same sound 30 times). To me the notification sound should just stick to the user preference.

Comment: 30 notifications??? what if it were play the sound one hour, would you fire 3600 notifications??? whats the idea behind it?

Comment: The idea is to play the notification sound repeatedly and stop if the notification is cancelled or clicked by the user.

Comment: @RichardTingle play longer sounds means longer sound file that would mean more over head on the APK file esp. if I have several sound files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answered my question. FLAG_INSISTENT repeatedly played the sound until the user open the notification pool. No need for the 'for' loop.

```
// turn on the alarm
notification.sound = soundUri;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
// after 30 seconds turn off the alarm
new Handler().postDelayed(
    new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                notification.flags ^= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
                notificationManager.notify(tag, NOTIFICATION_ID,   
                    notification);
            }
    }, 30000);
```