# How can we detect notification cancel?

Tags: android, notifications

How can I react on notification dismiss? I need to kill my background process when a certain notification is cancelled.

In this thread it says use a broadcast receiver, but there is no intent-filter for notifications

[Notification deleteIntent does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811876/notification-deleteintent-does-not-work)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need an intent-filter to get a broadcast if you define the Intent to trigger your class by hand.

Just implement the BroadcastReceiver

```
public class NotificationDeleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // kill service here
    }
}
```

And add the Receiver to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="NotificationDeleteReceiver" />
```

Then set the PendingIndent to the notification:

```
notification.deleteIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    this, 0, new Intent(context, NotificationDeleteReceiver.class), 0);
```

This will work.